# Deep copy a node in C#

Tags: c#, tree, nodes, deep-copy, shallow-copy

So long story short I have a tree with Nodes. I have to copy the information of one Node to another, but when I change the second Node, the fisrt changes too. I have made this method in the Node class :

```
public Node DeepCopyNode(Node node)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(node.Name, node.NodeТype, node.ParentExist, node.TagArguments, node.Parent, node.Children, node.NumberInCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        if (node.Children[i] != null)
        {
            DeepCopyNode(node.Children[i]);
        }
    }
    return newNode;
}
```

I tried to make Deep copy of the Node, but unfortunately didn't work. If somebody have any suggestions what to do, please write it down :)

Comment: the question is: how deep is deep? Currently you're just referencing the nodes `Parent` as well as it's `Children`. So chances are you need to copy those before. Which will recursivly deep copy their parents and so on. So you end up copying your entire tree. Is that what you want? Then you shouldn't copy the tree via an arbitrary node, but just via its root.

Comment: you're not using the functions return-value BTW.

Comment: `Node newNode = new Node(node.Name, node.NodeТype, node.ParentExist, node.TagArguments, node.Parent, node.Children, node.NumberInCount);` - Do yourself a favor: If you actually need a copy CTOR then make one: `public Node( Node node ){ ...}`

Comment: Question: Do you only need a copy of the `Node`'s data? Or a copy of _exactly_ that `Node` or a deep copy of the complete subtree?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make a deep copy of an object is to deserialize it's serialized version:

```
var newNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(node));
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Node newNode = new Node(... node.Parent, node.Children ...);
> ```

This is wrong. You cannot use the parent or children of the node you are copying if you want a deep copy. It should look something like

```
public Node DeepCopyNode(Node node, Node parent)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(..., parent, new List<Node>(), ...);
    var children = node.Children.Select(c => DeepCopyNode(c, newNode )).ToList();
    newNode.Children.AddRange(children); 
    return newNode;          
}
```

All this assumes only the tree needs deep copying, not any other values stored in the tree.